# Magento2 product conditions

Tags: php, magento2

Magento2 has that nice UI to provide conditions to filter products, cart attributes etc. I could not find any documentation how such functionality should be extended for custom module.

Based on `module-catalog-rule` and `module-sales-rule` modules I was able to implement conditions UI and saving corresponding values(`conditions_serialized`) but I am not able to apply those conditions to get filtered products.

So the **question**: How can I implement conditions in a custom module? How can I use(apply) conditions?

[image: conditions]

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3133 holds the answer